# Getting google calendar calendarId from DOM at calendar.google.com

Tags: javascript, dom, web-scraping, google-calendar-api

Is there a way to find out calendar ID of event in google.calendar.com from DOM?
I need to be able to scrape it from DOM from both full calendar view when event is clicked and when event is opened in full/edit mode.

I'm able to find eventId by this, but I need calendar ID too to be able to do some Calendar API actions:

`$('div[data-eventid]').attr('data-eventid');`

Comment: I think from DOM you have no chances to do that, since calendarID is not displayed in DOM but only in each calendar settings page. Are you using Google API for those interactions, or what are you doing?
If you can share more information it could be helpful...

Comment: Yes, I'm using Google Calendar API. Basically I'm adding a button to those calendar views which when clicked invites predefined email to that event. I do this by updating attendees list using event.update endpoint in API. Problem is that this API requires both eventID and calendarID. For primary calendar, calendarID is always == 'primary' but I don't know how to find calendarID for non-primary calendar events

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this.
You have to take the ID that you got from "data-eventid" and base64 decode it.
Once decoded you will find 2 values that are space delimited:

```
event-id calender-id
```